# createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

> I'm trying to get data from youtube API but get a bed request like
>   this: Request failed with status code 400. below code in Youtube.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
const KEY = 'AIzaSyDg1vwi_QOn6zNEaFGL8OWTGD2qWAEDnvE';

export default axios.create({
   baseURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3',
   params: {
      part: 'snippet',
      maxResults: 5,
      key: KEY
   }
})
```

> Then I import it in my App.js and below code in App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';
import Youtube from '../Api/Youtube';

class App extends React.Component {

  onSearchSubmit = async (term) => {
    const response = await Youtube.get('/search', {
      params: {
        q: term
      }
    })

    console.log(response)
  }
  render() {
    return (
       <div className="ui container" style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}>
        <SearchBar Akib={this.onSearchSubmit} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi, in the Network tab of your dev tools - do you get some more informations about the error ?

Answer (score 0):

try to put your params that exists in api.js in your app.js so your code in app.js code gonna be something like this, after all  , when you run your app look inside your network requests in your google developer tools (ctrl + shift + i ) and look for the params that you send   :

```
const KEY = 'AIzaSyBG9i-nVtQ5riZkaCwz4iTC1neYb5-G9A8';

    youtube.get('/search',{
        params :{
            q:term,
            key :KEY,
            part: 'snippet',
            maxResults : 5,
```